# What does ``` var num = 200_200 ``` mean in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am learning kotlin through codecademy and came across this exercise where we were learning operators like `+ - % /` then I noticed this line of code and din't understand could someone please explain?

`var Num = 200_200`

That is the line of code.

Comment: It's just formatting. It's the same as `var Num = 200200` https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#underscores-in-numeric-literals-since-11

Comment: Thanks the linked helped a lot

Comment: It doesn't affect the code. It just makes it easier to read the number like (`1_000`, `12_359` , etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_` is ignored by the compiler.
It's only there for readability.

You can use `_` as a delimiter, dividing numbers into more readable parts.
In your example, you use the `_` as a thousand delimiter.
But if you want to work with bits at some point, you can also use `_` to delimit bytes, e.g., `0010_1010`.

Kotlin reference:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#underscores-in-numeric-literals-since-11

Comment: And to spell this out: **the underscore is ignored**.  It's a like a comment: there to help the reader, but ignored by the compiler.